# Status message appears multiple times on status stream

Tags: users

I have user relationship and Status modules installed. Each time a user posts a message on his/her profile it appears 12 times in his/her status stream while it appears once in other users stream.

Please does anyone know what can be wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug in a module, and bugs should be posted in module's issue queue. Unless you have some reasons to believe problem is in your setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://drupal.org/node/1478962) that module uses Views to create the blocks, so it could be just a matter of "Reduce Duplicates" on the filters, or checking the "Distinct" option on the view itself.